# File appears in windows explorer but not in open box

Tags: windows, security, windows-explorer

I have a box running Windows Server 2008 R2.

If I look at a certain directory with Windows Explorer -- c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config -- I see 2 subdirectories and 3 files.

Then I go into a program and use an open box to open a file. I navigate to that directory. I can see the 2 subdirectories, but no files appear. If I type in the name of the file (applicationHost.cofnig), it says that it does not exist.

I've tried this with Notepad++, Wordpad, and Filezilla Client. The filter is set to *.*.

What's really killing me is that I'm trying to open this file from within a VB program, and it's saying not found.

Oh, and here's a kicker: If I access the file with a UNC name, then it works. That is, trying to open "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config" gives a not-found. But if I write "\server1\c$\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config", then it works. If I change my VB program to use a UNC name, it works. So I suppose I have a work-around, but I'd really like to understand what's going on.

If instead of logging into the server, I run Notepad++ on my desktop, and enter \server1\c$ and then navigate from there, all three files show up.

Oh, and also, if in Windows Explorer I right-click the file and select "edit with notepad++", it opens. But from within Notepad++, trying to use the open box doesn't work. I tried navigating through the directory tree, and I tried just typing in the full path. Either way, "not found".

I checked my permissions and it says I have "full access" to the directory and to the file.

Comment: Go to Prompt, change directory and type `dir`. Are there all files? In File Open dialog, type `*` for filename and hit Enter.

Comment: @i486 Yes, if I do a dir on the directory from a command prompt, the files appear. Within Notepad++, if I type `*` for the filename, the files do not appear. I also tried a couple of variations that would include the desired file name, like `*.config` and `a*`, and those also showed nothing.

Comment: It seems the last dir `config` has special rights. I was not able to open it in Windows Explorer without going to admin rights. Run Notepad+ as administrator and try again.

Comment: Are you by any chance running a 32-bit app on 64-bit Windows? If so, you may be experiencing WOW64 folder redirection - attempts to access `c:\windows\system32` get redirected to `c:\windows\syswow64`.

Comment: I did try running Notepad++ as admin. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: @AndrewMedico !!! That appears to be it. I created a file in the syswow64 directory and sure enough, it shows up in Notepad++ when I open system32. Thank you Microsoft for knifing me in the back. I guess my VB app is compiling to 32 bit, I'll have to check on settings. Or just use the UNC name, as that works.

Comment: Why are people voting to close? This seems to me to be a perfectly valid question, and I got an extremely useful answer.